# SimpleCursorAdapter deprecated in API version 15?

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

**SimpleCursorAdapter** deprecates one of its constructors with the following comment:

Deprecated. This option is discouraged, as it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI thread and thus can cause poor responsiveness or even Application Not Responding errors. As an alternative, use android.app.LoaderManager with a android.content.CursorLoader.

Does this make the whole class deprecated? The other (standard) constructor is not deprecated.

Comment: do you have an example of how to use an adapter with the LoadManager and CursorLoader ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Only the constructor is deprecated, not the whole class.

[`SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) calls [`SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29) with `flags` set to [`FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY).

But `FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY` is deprecated because

> [...] it results in Cursor queries being performed on the application's UI
>   thread [...]

so also the constructor is deprecated.

The standard constructor is not deprecated but, obviously, you don't have to call it with `flags` = `FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY`!

Finally, if you are using `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a `CursorLoader`, as the documentation suggests, 
this flag is not needed and you can pass `0`.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html