# SimpleCursorAdapter alternative

Tags: android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I'm using the deprecated SimpleCursorAdapter to display data from Cursor to ListView. I've added the additional argument `0`, which removes the dreprecated warning, but I want to use a better way to display data. I've read something about `Loader`, but don't know how to implement it. What would be a better alternative to the code below? How would this code be translated to use Loader?

```
Cursor c = mDbHelper.getAllRecords();
    startManagingCursor(c); //this is also deprecated

    String[] from = new String[] { "Name" };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter names =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.names_row, c, from, to, 0);
    setListAdapter(names);
```

Comment: "but I want to use a better way to display data." A Loader only reads the data from your database on another thread, it doesn't change the way the data is displayed. You should change `names_row.xml` to alter the way it is displayed.

Comment: Switching to Loaders is not a trivial matter using only Android classes. You need to create a ContentProvider first and then implement the Loader framework. However [CommonsWare](http://stackoverflow.com/u/115145/) has written [a Loader library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) that doesn't require ContentProviders. Here is [a tutorial](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/) that covers both approaches.

Answer (score 7):

`adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor, from, to, 1);`

This will do the automatic requery. 1 is set to true and 0 to false.

Answer (score 6):

SimpleCursorAdapter isn't deprecated, just the constructor.

see [SimpleCursorAdapter deprecated in API version 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790659/simplecursoradapter-deprecated-in-api-version-15)