# SimpleCursorAdapter deprecated, what to do now?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been working through a tutorial on using Androids SQLite Database.  The tutorial is found here: http://coenraets.org/blog/androidtutorial/

I am stuck on step three, everything in android studio shows that there are no errors.  But I cant seem to query the database, it wont show results when I press the search button.  Is it because of this SimpleCursorAdapter being deprecated? If so, how would I go about making this database work.

```
**MAIN ACTIVITY(EMPLOYEELIST.java)**
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        protected EditText searchText;
        protected SQLiteDatabase db;
        protected Cursor cursor;
        protected ListAdapter adapter;
        protected ListView employeeList;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
            searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);
            employeeList = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
        }

        public void search(View view) {
            // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?",
                    new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.employee_list_item,
                    cursor,
                    new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"},
                    new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
            employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter` is not deprecated. Even If it was, it would still work, so that is not your problem.

Comment: It tells me right in android studio that it is....

Comment: It does not say so anywhere in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html).

Comment: So do you see any other way to do what i need done?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context, int, android.database.Cursor, java.lang.String[], int[])

Comment: As posted above with a pic, it looks like its deprecated..

Answer (score 3):

Only the constructor is deprecated, not the whole class.

The standard constructor is not deprecated but, obviously, you don't have to call it with `flags = FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY!`

Finally, if you are using SimpleCursorAdapter with a `CursorLoader`, as the documentation suggests, this flag is not needed and you can pass 0.

Please check this link

[SimpleCursorAdapter deprecated in API version 15?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790659/simplecursoradapter-deprecated-in-api-version-15)