# What to use instead of SimpleCursorAdapter() in Android Studio- API 23

Tags: android

I have used a code that works with SimpleCursorAdapter but in this version of Android it has been depreciated totally. So what to use instead? Because of this setListAdapter is also having errors. As i cannot lose the whole code for this one error, is there any method that can replace this? There has to be some solution.

```
 ListAdapter  adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.activity_display,
                c,
                new String[] {"Usn", "Attended", "Missed"},
                new int[] {R.id.Usn,R.id.Attended,R.id.Missed});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleCursorAdapter deprecated in API version 15?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790659/simplecursoradapter-deprecated-in-api-version-15)

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleCursorAdapter` is not deprecated. Only the constructor you are using is deprecated. Technically you can still use this constructor, but it's better to use the [other constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int)) that has an additional argument. (You can pass `0` as the last argument if you don't need the adapter to automatically requery the cursor.)

Comment: thanx for the quick reply. But what other constructor? Can you please mention it? There a few constructors in the link. Which should i use?

Comment: @beginner The words "other constructor" in my post link directly to it. The only other constructor is the (deprecated) one you are already using.